# Debugging 'testthat' tests in RStudio

Tags: r, debugging, testing, rstudio, testthat

Is it possible to invoke the debugger in RStudio when running `testthat` tests?  I haven't been able to find a setup that allows this (various combinations of "use `devtools` package functions if available" in the settings, hitting the "Test Package" option in the "Build -> More" menu, running `test()` in the console, putting in `browser()` calls, etc.) but haven't found a way yet.

I also find myself getting lost a lot when testing, unsure whether the code being run has been installed in the system libraries (by doing 'Build & Reload'), or is being run *in situ* from the local `R` directory, or what - sometimes RStudio complains that a breakpoint can't be set until the package is rebuilt (so I suspect the former) or doesn't (so I suspect the latter).  Not sure if this issue is closely related or not to my main question.

Without finding a way to drop into the debugger, I end up pasting test code into the console & working in a very ad-hoc fashion, and basically shooting my TDD habits in the foot.  So any advice would be appreciated - if it's not possible to invoke the debugger, any suggested workarounds?

I'm running RStudio version 0.99.447 on OS X, in local mode, with R 3.2.1.

**Edit** - I'd also love to know more background about the options, e.g. "option X will never support debugging, because it's running in a forked process, try this other option Y instead."

**Update** - having had no responses here, I also asked at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/204779797-Debugging-testthat-tests-in-RStudio (where I also haven't had any responses).

Answer (score 36):

The following works for me:

1. Insert a call to `browser()` somewhere within the testthat unit tests.
2. Run `devtools::test()` from the RStudio console (instead of using the "Test Package" menu item from the UI)

Then, when the test runner hits the `browser()` invocation, you should be able to use the [environment browser](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/browser.html) and step through the code.

I haven't found a way to get testthat to stop at breakpoints, but inserting `browser()` invocations is a pretty close substitute.

To be absolutely sure that you're starting from a consistent state when it comes to loading packages, you can close RStudio, re-open it, run "Clean and rebuild", and then `devtools::test()`

Lastly, if you're working within an RStudio package, you may want to check out the following advice from [RStudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#debugging-in-packages):

> In order to debug effectively in your package, you’ll also want to ensure that your package is compiled with the --with-keep.source option. This option is the default for new packages in RStudio; if you need to set it manually, it can be found in Tools -> Project Options -> Build Tools.

Comment: By "Clean and rebuild" do you mean "Build & Reload"?  The thing I really hate about that is that I often accidentally install my development version globally on the machine by doing it.  `dev_mode` is one solution but sometimes I forget to turn that on too, since it's a manual process...

Comment: I'm hesitant to use the `browser()` method either - recently someone on my team (not me, thankfully!) left a bunch of `browser()` statements in their code, which went to production, which was bad.  It's a bummer to have to alter the code just to scrutinize it.  Although it's not quite as bad in this case to do it in the test files - for some reason when using `devtools::test()` breakpoints don't work in the test files, but they do work in the code files under the `R/` directory.

Comment: No, there's a separate "Clean and rebuild" command, which as far as I can tell is the same as "Build & reload" but performs some initial cleanup to get into a more predictable state.

Comment: Also, based on the following discussions, it looks like the lack of support for breakpoints in testthat is a known issue, but not yet fixed as of this writing:
[discussion 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rdevtools/pB9ovKCh-tQ), 
[discussion 2](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/issues/116)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the pointer.  I've added a "poke" on https://github.com/hadley/testthat/pull/117 .

Comment: Coming back to an old thread - I never use "Clean and Rebuild" or "Build and Reload" anymore.  I only use "Load All", which is quick and doesn't install globally.  "Document" is also necessary sometimes if imports need to be adjusted.

Comment: I have tried following you suggestions with `browser()` but testthat still does not stop at breakpoints, `--with-keep.source` is set. Tried re-opening RStudio and running "Clean and rebuild" to no avail. Do you know by any chance what else it may be?

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use editor breakpoints from RStudio in order to debug unit tests, you can do it by working around `testthat`. As Hadley said in a Github issue, testthat usually runs in a separate session from RStudio, so it won't ever be able to use editor breakpoints. However, the tests, themselves, are function calls with two arguments, a description and code. You can read these and run them with a little code.

```
testf_trace <- function(filename, match) {
  env <- new.env()

  test_that <- function(desc, code) {
    if (length(grep(match, desc)) > 0) {
      eval(substitute(code), env)
    }
  }
  env$test_that <- test_that
  source(filename, env)
}
```

If you have a test that reads `test_that("invariant is true", { f(3) == 6 })`, then you can test this by running `testf_trace(filename, "is true")`.

If you're unsure where a function is defined, and hence whether the breakpoint will work, you can find out by typing the name of the function at the console. The last line or two will tell you in which environment the function is defined, if it was defined in an environment other than .Global.